# Unit testing with Mockito resets a mocked class' instance variable to null

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, testng, mockito

I have mocked a Message class as follows (within a TestNG unit test class):

```
@BeforeMethod
protected void setUp() {
    message = mock(Message.class);
}
```

I can assure you that I have declared `message` of type `Message` in the Unit test class. Now, the `Message` class has an instance variable called `category` which is of type String as follows:

```
public class Message {
    private String category;

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

Okay, now the problem: within a small test method, I have to set the `category` of a mocked `message` instance and then use that `category` for another task in the unit test. However, after I set the `category` for the `mocked` message, it reverts to `null` again. This is the code:

```
public void shouldSendMessagesWithCategory() {
    message.setCategory("F1 Racing"); // SET THE CATEGORY

    raceResults.addSubscriber("F1 Racing", clientA); 
    System.out.println("Cat" + message.getCategory()); // THE MESSAGE's CATEGORY IS NULL

    raceResults.send(message);

    verify(clientA).receive(message);
}
```

The console prints out `null` - so I definitely know it's `null`. I've been trying to figure this out for two days, but it just seems I'm missing something. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Becouse of using mock (setCategory does nothing - it is empty). You should use spy instead of mock or mock getCategory method from Message mock object.

Comment: `Message` most probable is a _value type_. Value types should not be mocked. Simply use them in your tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [spy()](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Spy.html) instead of `Mock()`. Then you can keep the set value. You have another option. You can use `doReturn("F1 Racing").when(message).getCategory();` to return the value you want to return.

Comment: Ahh, now I get it. Mocked objects do not keep state. It makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The "message" handle does not point to a real Message object - it points to a mock'ed object which has none of the functionality of the real thing. If you want the mock'ed object to return a value from getCategory() you will have to mock that too. Something like:

```
when(message.getCategory()).thenReturn("My Category");
```